# Are virtual properties slower than concrete properties?

Tags: c#, performance, oop, visual-c++, interface

Say I have a C# interface called `IMyInterface` defined as follows:

```
// C# code
public interface IMyInterface
{
  string MyProperty { get; }
}
```

Assume I also have a C++/CLI class, `MyConcreteClass`, that implements this interface and whose header is declared as follows:

```
public ref class MyConcreteClass : public IMyInterface
{
 public:
  virtual property String^ MyProperty 
  {
    String^ get() sealed { return String::Empty; };
    void set( String^ s ) sealed { };
  }
};
```

Obviously when you access a virtual member through the interface, the runtime must look for an implementation in the class, and will be slower than if the member was not virtual.

```
IMyInterface obj;
obj->MyProperty = "HELLO";
```

I'm asking specifically about the performance of using virtual members directly on the concrete object type. Is this slower if `MyProperty` was a virtual member?

```
MyConcreteClass obj;
obj->MyProperty = "HELLO";
```

Comment: Do some benchmarking and see the result.

Comment: There's this saying: The numbers tell the tale. Do a run with a tight loop a few hundred-thousand or even million times with a virtual and concrete property and *measure* the difference. There's a reason why Profilers and perdformance analyzers exist ;)

Comment: That sounds like a case of premature micro-optimization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Virtual methods are slower because the runtime has to check for an actual implementation of the method. So it is 1 additional check. You can still hundreds of thousands of these per second. So don't stress about it. In Java every method is virtual by default.

UPDATE:
I am not sure about how introducing c++ changes things. My guess is that is would be similar because you are still accessing a virtual method. I am not sure how it would change it. But once again this is just my guess. Hopefully someone else can help out more.

Comment: I updated my question with the specific data I'm looking for. Can you update your answer to reflect?